# when repetitively manipulating small amounts of HTML, how to balance readability versus maintainability?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have 2 divs that load a similar list (but different data) which I can load in the following 2 ways through Javascript:

```
function loadApprovalPanels() {
    // CSS selector selects all elements of type div where the id ends in ApprovalsActionsPane.
    query("div[id$='ApprovalsActionsPane']").forEach(function(approvalPane){
        loadApprovalPanel(approvalPane);
    });
```

OR:

```
function loadApprovalPanels() {
    var preApprovalPane = dom.byId("preApprovalsActionsPane");
    var postApprovalPane = dom.byId("postApprovalsActionsPane");
    if (preApprovalPane) {
        loadApprovalPanel(preApprovalPane);
    }
    if (postApprovalPane) {
        loadApprovalPanel(postApprovalPane);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which of these 2 versions would be best from a combination of maintainability and readability.

The second function is the simplest (just 2 dom queries, 2 ifs and 2 function calls), but it also essentially does the same thing twice, but with just a string change. The first function has no duplicate code, but it's slightly harder to read considering it contains a CSS selector and a loop.

Both functions inherently do the same thing, and it works, but this is a case where maintainability (prefer no duplicate code) and readability (prefer easy to understand code) compete with each other. I'm not concerned about speed because at this small amount of dom manipulation, they both work fast enough.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: You could create an array or object that would map the names and actions. Then loop through the elements to use it.

Comment: @user2182349 I think that at this small scale, that would be needlessly complex. I already store the action to use to load the panel as a property of the div.